# Setting a binding for a second window

Tags: c#, mvvm, datacontext

I have two WPF windows and i want to set the context to a ViewModel but if I write:

```
this.DataContext = new myViewModel()
```

in my second windows cs it doesn't work here is my code. i have tried to place a binding in the XAML and to connect the context but when i try to debug it all i get the error code this breakpoint will not get run.

BrowseDialog.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="TextalkApi.BrowseDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextalkApi"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BrowseDialog" Height="248.361" Width="427.459">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="FileDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding webUrl}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244"/>
        <Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding errorMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.611,10.822" Width="207" Height="19"/> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

BrowseViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;

namespace Data
{
    public class BrowseViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region public variables
        public string webUrl { get; set; }
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Public Commands
        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public BrowseViewModel()
        {
            this.SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveFilePath);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private methods
        private void SaveFilePath()
        {
            if (File.Exists(webUrl))
            {
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add("WebUrl", webUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Filen existerar ej"; 
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

BrowseDialog.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using Data;

namespace TextalkApi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BrowseDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BrowseDialog : Window
    {
        public BrowseDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new BrowseViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using PropertyChanged;

namespace Data
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]

    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem here that the error message does not get displayed? Can you clarify in your question please. I suspect it is, and in that case in the setter of the errorMessage property there is no call to NotifyPropertyChanged or similar, I suspect you have a method in your ViewModelBase that will set a property and automatically call a method that implements this.

Comment: Yes this is close to the question but it doesnt seem like the breakpoint eaven has the possibility to get hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML looks correct and I highly suspect it is the ViewModel causing it not to work. Something like this should work.

Please note that this will depend a lot on how the BaseViewModel has been implemented. If possible can you share this so I can update my answer to be correct? The below is how you should implement the properties in your ViewModel which is the DataContext of the View.

```
#region Properties
    private string _webUrl;
    public string WebUrl 
    { 
        get => _webUrl;     
        set 
        {
            //This will change based on how you have implemented your BaseViewModel!
            //The method name might be different, or have different parameters!
            this.SetProperty(ref _webUrl, value, nameof(WebUrl));
            //Call the save file path validation method...
            SaveFilePath();
        }
    }

    private string _errorMessage;
    public string ErrorMessage 
    { 
        get => _errorMessage;           
        private set 
        {
            //This will change based on how you have implemented your BaseViewModel!
            //This method should call NotifyPropertyChange to notify the UI to update...
            this.SetProperty(ref _errorMessage, value, nameof(ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
#endregion
```

In your ViewModelBase you can add a generic SetProperty method that can then handle raising the property changed event for you. Something like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and because of the changes in the ViewModel you will also need to update the bindings in your XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="FileDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding WebUrl}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244"/>
    <Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ErrorMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.611,10.822" Width="207" Height="46"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ViewModel base, I can't see anything in their that raises this event. I will update my anwser with a simple example.

Comment: The top part of your answer where should i add it i get inside the viewmodel but just as if i were adding a property?

Comment: Yes, apologies the top part is properties in the ViewModel. It goes in whichever ViewModel is the DataContext of the View.

Comment: In the XAML on your Label try Content="{Binding errorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: nope not working it doesnt update but i still think though that the command is somehow wrong no?

Comment: Have you verified that the Method is hitting and setting the errorMessage property by stepping through it?

Comment: the breakpoints will not get hit i have no clue why the datacontext doesnt work

Comment: How are you creating and showing the second window? I assume you are doing this.DataContext = new BrowseViewModel() not myViewModel (guessing this was just for the original question)

Comment: ? i created a new window in my solution and from there i am showing BrowseWindow and then im connecting it in the way you are saying i am

Comment: Hmm this is very odd. I don't suppose you're able to upload the project somewhere for me to take a look? Understand if this is not an option.

Comment: Sorry do not see a possibilty for that sadly

Comment: No worries I understand, I will take your code into a new project. What Nuget package(s) are you using MVVMLightLibs?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the corrected XAML . Hopefully this resolves the issue for you.

Comment: Sadly this did not .D

Comment: i get the error no symbols have been loaded for this document

Comment: Hmm it was working on my project. I suggest you check all the casing of properties and method bindings as these are case sensitive.

Comment: well basicly it doesnt run the BrowseViewModel at all

Comment: Sorry for the no answer though i am using PropertyChanged.Fody